# Generating single random number in pyCuda kernel

Tags: python, cuda, random-seed, pycuda

I have seen many ways to generate an array of random numbers. but I want to generate a single random number. Is there any function as rand() in c++. I don't want a series of random numbers. I just need to generate a random number inside the kernel. is there any builtin function to generate random numbers?  I have tried the given code below, but it not working.

```
import numpy as np
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
from pycuda import gpuarray

code = """
    #include <curand_kernel.h>
       __device__ float getRand()
       {
          curandState_t s;
          curand_init(clock64(), 123456, 0, &s);
          return curand_uniform(&s);
       }

        __global__ void myRand(float *values)
        {
          values[0] = getRand();
        }
"""


mod = SourceModule(code)
myRand = mod.get_function("myRand")
gdata = gpuarray.zeros(2, dtype=np.float32)
myRand(gdata, block=(1,1,1), grid=(1,1,1))
print(gdata)
```

Errors are like:

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/curand_poisson.h(548): error: this declaration may not have extern "C" linkage

/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/curand_discrete2.h(69): error: this declaration may not have extern "C" linkage

/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/curand_discrete2.h(78): error: this declaration may not have extern "C" linkage

/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/curand_discrete2.h(86): error: this declaration may not have extern "C" linkage

30 errors detected in the compilation of "kernel.cu".
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem is that, by default, PyCUDA [silently applies C linkage](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#pycuda.compiler.SourceModule) to all code compiled in a `SourceModule`. As the error is showing, `cuRand` requires C++ linkage, so `getRand` can't have C linkage.

You can fix this either by changing these two lines:

```
mod = SourceModule(code)
myRand = mod.get_function("myRand")
```

to

```
mod = SourceModule(code, no_extern_c=True)
myRand = mod.get_function("_Z6myRandPf")
```

This disables C linkage, but does mean you need to supply the C++ mangled name to the `get_function` call. You will need to look at the verbose compiler output or compile the code outside of PyCUDA to get that name (for example [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9xThhYfba)).

Alternatively you can modify the code like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
from pycuda import gpuarray

code = """
       #include <curand_kernel.h>

       __device__ float getRand()
       {
          curandState_t s;
          curand_init(clock64(), 123456, 0, &s);
          return curand_uniform(&s);
       }
        
        extern "C" {
        __global__ void myRand(float *values)
        {
          values[0] = getRand();
        }
        }
"""


mod = SourceModule(code, no_extern_c=True)
myRand = mod.get_function("myRand")
gdata = gpuarray.zeros(2, dtype=np.float32)
myRand(gdata, block=(1,1,1), grid=(1,1,1))
print(gdata)
```

This leaves the kernel with C linkage, but doesn't touch the device function which is using cuRand.

Answer (score -4):

you can `import random` in python . and use `random.randint()`. to generate random number in specified range by defining range in function. ex`random.randint(0,50)`

Comment: I want to generate random number in the kernel, not in python. Actually, I have written a lot of code in C++/C and I need to generate a random number in kernel to complete my task.